# Minimising a convex set. Is set of solutions convex?

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, linear-programming

We are minimising a convex function on a non-empty set defined by linear constraints (equalities and inequalities). $X^O$ is the set of all optimal solutions and we assume it is non-empty. Is it true that $X^O$ is a convex set?

I think it is not as for example in the case of the function $f(x)=x^2$ defined on $X=(-\infty, -1]\cup[1,\infty)$ we have got minimas at $x=-1$ and $x=1$, however, clearly this set is not convex. Am I right and is my example correct? Is such function defined in such a way convex?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "defined by linear constraints"?

Comment: I am not really sure, but this is exactly what question says.

Comment: When you say that $ X $ is defined by linear constraints, do you mean that $ X = \{ x: Ax=b, Cx \leq d\} $ for some matrices $ A, C $ and vectors $ b, d $? If so, then $(-\infty,-1]\cup [1,\infty) $ is not "defined by linear constraints".

Comment: Ah yes, exactly. In this case, how to proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement *is true*.

As mentioned in the comments, your example constraint set cannot be generated by an intersection of linear constraints. The intersection of linear constraints must be a convex set:

- A linear inequality is a half-space which is a convex set.
- A linear equality is a hyperplane which is also convex.
- The intersection of convex sets is convex.

The minimizers of a convex function on a convex set are a convex set since the lower contour set of a convex function is convex.

Answer (score 3):

In general, consider minimizing a convex function $f$ on a convex set $C$. Let $\mathcal M \subseteq C$ be the set of minimizers. Choose any $(a, b, t) \in \mathcal M^2 \times [0, 1]$. Then for any $x \in C$, we have

$$f(ta + (1-t)b) \le tf(a) + (1-t)f(b) \le tf(x) + (1-t)f(x) = f(x),$$
and so $ta + (1-t)b$ is a minimizer of $f$. Also, by convexity of $C$, we have $ta + (1-t)b \in C$, and so $ta + (1-t)b \in \mathcal M$. We conclude that $\mathcal M$ is indeed convex.